# Python: Pseudo Enums - Classes as enums - how to avoid cyclic import

Tags: python-3.x, enums, python-import

I want to create a pseudo enums in my python project.
The values are actually classes.

```
# file my_enums.py

import MyClass1
import MyClass2
import MyClass3

class MyEnum:
    MY_CLASS_1 = MyClass1
    MY_CLASS_2 = MyClass2
    MY_CLASS_3 = MyClass3



# file my_class1.py
import MyEnum

class MyClass1:
    def foo(self, x):
        print(isinstance(x, MyEnum.MY_CLASS_2))
```

Doing this will result in cyclic import error.
I want to be able to use the MyEnum values in isinstance function and to import the enum to modules that define some of those classes.
Is there a way to do so?

Solution:

```
# file my_enums.py

import MyClass1
import MyClass2
import MyClass3

class MyEnum:

    MY_CLASS_1 = None
    MY_CLASS_2 = None
    MY_CLASS_3 = None
    
    @classmethod
    def define(cls):
        cls.MY_CLASS_1 = MyClass1

MyEnum.define()
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is that when a module is loaded, it is executed -- but only top level statements and the immediate interior of top-level classes; the bodies of functions and methods are not evaluated until they are actually called.

```
# example module

CONSTANT = 7                    # top-level, executed

def a_func(value=CONSTANT):     # top-level, executed
    return value + 9            # body, not executed

class a_class(metaclass=SomeMeta):  # top-level, executed (and error as SomeMeta
                                    # has not been defined nor imported)
    CLS_CONSTANT = 3                # top-level class body, executed

    def a_method(self):             # executed
        return self.CLS_CONSTANT + FUTURE_CONSTANT  # method body, not executed

FUTURE_CONSTANT = 11
```

So in your example you need to make sure and not use `MyEnum` anywhere in `my_class1.py` that will be executed during import, and put the import of `my_enums.py` at the very end -- then when `my_enums.py` is executed during its import it will be able to import `my_class1` which will, at that point, have the classes defined.